# Why isn't "first-child" pseudo-class working on table-row (tr) elements when the first one is inside a "div"?

Tags: html, css

```css
tr:first-child {
    background-color:lime;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <div>
        <tr>
            <th>Something</th>
        </tr>
    </div>

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I've used "div" as a parent container for the first "tr". So in this case, 'first-child' should apply to the "tr" of the "div" container, and the first "tr" of the "table" parent, yet the first-child applies only to the first "tr" inside the div-container. Why?

first-child should apply to the first child-element of a parent container. The first child-element of a parent container is the th-element, and the first-child element of the table-parent is the first td element.

It seems that the table tag structure is messing things up here, but i don't know how exactly.

NOTE:

Yes, i know that the table structure is invalid, but that shouldn't matter for the way child-element pseudo-class works.

Here is another example using "div" container instead.

```
<div>

<p>first paragrapth</p>

<div>

    <p>First paragrapth of the div container</p>

</div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
p:first-child {
    background-color:red;
    }
```

This example is essentially the same, only instead of using "table" i have used "div". Why is the first-child pseudo-class working the way it should be working in this case, but not for the "table" example? Is it solely because the usage of "div" inside the "table" messes up the table tag structure, and that causes the pseudo-class to not recognize the other "table-rows" as first child-elements of the table-parent?

Comment: your's is not a valid markup, table only direct child can be tbody or tr, swap tr & div .

Comment: if you don't add the CSS tag to your question (which is very relevant to many of them) you won't get accurate answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the selector `:first-child` looks for the first element in a parent like you've said, in this case `tr`. For example if I want the first paragraphs to have `background-color: yellow`.

```css
p:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>This paragraph is the first child inside of a div.</p>
</div>

<p>This paragraph is the second child.</p>
<p>This paragraph is the third child.</p>
```

However, inside of your code the first `tr` is the first child in the div but also of the table. Therefor only the first `tr` is selected

Comment: But shouldn't first-child apply to any first child-element of a parent container? In this example here - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild , the first-child applies to the first "p" which is the child-element of the body container, and then it also applies to the first "p" of the "div" container. Why isn't the same thing happening in my example?

Comment: You're not wrong, but that just isn't how css works. In your example when you surround that first child with a `div` that doesn't mean that it isn't the first child anymore.

Comment: I am sorry i am not sure i understand your point. The first TR in my example is the first child-element of the div container, and then the second TR below it is the first-child element of the table container. Is that not correct? Does the pseudo-class not recognize the second TR as the first-child element of the table-container because of the div?

Comment: Check the snippet inside of my answer, a `div` does not magically change it from being the first child

Comment: I am a bit confused. What do you mean div doesn't change its child-element from being the first child-element? The first "p" child-element in your example is the first "p" inside the div, but why isn't the second "p" getting highlighted too, since it's also the first child-element of the body container? Look at my additional example. The first "p" child-element is the first-child of the body container, and then the second "p" is the first-child of the div container.

Comment: I just tested something. In the example i gave you in w3school, i put the div container on top, while the second "p" on the bottom, and now the first-child pseudo-class applies only to the first "p" of the div container, but it doesn't apply anymore to the second "p" below the div container. Why? Isn't the second "p" supposed to be the first-child of the body container?

Comment: Yes, css is kind of weird. The second `p` in my example is not getting selected as the first child because the `p` above it inside the `div` is. Selectors overlap each other, so while this `p` is the first inside of the `div` it also is the first for the body

Comment: I see. So, i understand that the first "p" is treated as the first-child of the "div" parent, and at the same time first-child of the body parent, but can you elaborate a little bit more on which selectors overlap in this case? Isn't the "first-child" selector the only selector in use here?

Answer (score 0):

Your's is not a valid markup, table only direct child can be tbody or tr, swap tr & div like so.

```css
tr:first-child{
background-color:lime;
}
```

```html
<table>

    
        <tr>
        
            <th>
              <div>
                Something
              </div>
            </th>
        
        </tr>
    

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>
        
    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: I know, but how is that related to the way first-child pseudo-class works?

Answer (score 0):

try this code to apply background color to first  element of each table row.

```css
td:first-child {
    background-color:lime;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Something</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Something Something</td>
        <td>Something Something</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```